# LazyInitializationException when using @Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to use Inheritance using this project https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration.

This is my User:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "TYPE")
public abstract class User {
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
     private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

and some subclass like UserAdmin:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ADMIN")
public class UserAdmin extends User {}
```

Then my role class is like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Role {
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
     private Collection<User> users;
}
```

But I got this error when I register a user:

> o.h.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.baeldung.persistence.model.Role.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Need help guys.

Comment: when you do many-to-many relations, they has to evaluate lazily since you cannot add 2 cycling data at the same time. check your code to see where you miss this requirements

Answer (score 1):

We need a bit more context, but you generally have two options:

1. Have the method where you call "getRoles()" be annotated with `@Transactional`.

or

2. Create a method in jpa with a `@Query("SELECT u from user u join fetch u.roles where u.id =:id")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've just download the project and introduced UserAdmin and UserStaff.
Got error when calling RegistrationController#confirmRegistration

Comment: I have add annotation to RegistrationController#authWithoutPassword but still got error

Comment: I just noticed that the project is a bit more complex, I think it should still work if you were to add @Transactional on RegistrationController#confirmRegistration.
But that is kinda a bad practice

Comment: indeed, not a good practice adding this annotation.